# Combining Two Color Maps

Tags: python, colorbar, colormap

I am attempting to combine two color maps into one grid. One is the yearly_mean_sss and the other is the yearly_mean_sm.

```
im = plt.imshow(yearly_mean_sm, cmap="jet", origin="lower")
cbar = plt.colorbar(im, shrink=1, orientation="horizontal", pad=0.08)
cbar.set_label('m^3 m^-3', fontsize=13)
plt.contourf(lons[0], lats[0], yearly_mean_sm, 60,
    transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), cmap="jet", extend="max")
```

What I have attempted so far is scaled one of the maps to fit the other via `np.resize()`. The other thing I did is make a for loop to plot each color map onto the grid but no luck.

For reference, below is the link for the color maps on separate grids.

https://github.com/Miggy070498/Joshua-Miguel-Bernardino-Portfolio/blob/main/images/SSS_Philippines.png

https://github.com/Miggy070498/Joshua-Miguel-Bernardino-Portfolio/blob/main/images/SM_Philippines.png

How can I combine these two?

EDIT: I just changed `yearly_mean_sm` to `yearly_mean_sss` to get one of the other images.

Comment: Is this a question about [colorbar positions](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/colorbar_placement.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-colorbar-placement-py) or [colormap normalization](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-colors-colormapnorms-py)? Or something else?

Comment: I think it has more to do with superimposing two color maps. Basically I want to place the colors in the second image onto the first. I hope that's clear.